# Facebook, Flash and Google App Engine

Tags: java, flash, google-app-engine, facebook

Is it possible to use a Facebook session in a Flash to authenticate on Google App Engine? I'm trying to create a Flash game and I want to use GAE as the back-end.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not totally sure I understand the question but I think you mean that you have a Facebook session running in Flash but you also want to be able to connect to your back end on GAE and have it interface with the FB REST API.

If so, then yes.  You simply create a URL for your GAE application that includes the FB authorization tokens (fb_sig*) and it should be able to re-use those to communicate with the Facebook API.

One caveat, though, is that the tokens may expire.  If you run across that problem then you'll simply need to re-auth with Facebook in the Flash and re-send the tokens to your GAE request.